# Primary Language setup inconsistency in the AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a very strange case.

Even though I chose primary language as a `Turkish`, but the Appstore shows `English`.

Does any one have any clues?

**iTunesConnect**  primary language is chosen `Turkish`

[image]

**Appstore** language is shown in `English`

[image]

Comment: Did you also actually localize your app? As far as I know the App Store shows the localized languages of the project and not the localized store data from iTunes Connect.

Comment: Why should I use localized language ? I am only supporting  Turkish language, no other language is supported. It should automatically use the Turkish since there is no other language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your info.plist file. You'll need to set `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` to Turkish

- "tr-CY" for  Turkish (Cyprus)
- "tr-TR for Turkish (Turkey)

Apple Doc links:

[Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH15-SW6)

[Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH15-SW6)